# How to type different words as variable entry data

Tags: c#, string, input, casting, character

I’m new to programming and I’m trying to write a code that does this:

Entry data

Name 1

Time 1

Name 2

Time 2

Output

Show the name that has the best time.

Now, I’ve managed to create a code that shows the correct result if I write the entry data like this:

A

200

B

300

(numbers are random)

Here is what I have tried so far -

```
 string inputdata = Console.ReadLine(); 
char name = Convert.ToChar(inputdata); 
inputdata = Console.ReadLine();
 double time1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputdata); 
inputdata = Console.ReadLine(); 
char name2 = Convert.ToChar(inputdata); 
inputdata = Console.ReadLine(); 
double time2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputdata); 
inputdata = Console.ReadLine(); 
if (time1 < time2) { Console.WriteLine(name); } 
else { Console.WriteLine(name2);
```

I don’t know how to type into the console the full name (any full word) so I don’t get “String must be exactly one character long”.

I’ve been strugling a bit with this and can’t seem to find the right answer.
Thank you!

Comment: Please, can you provide us with your code, so that we can see what did you try?

Comment: string inputdata = Console.ReadLine();
            char name = Convert.ToChar(inputdata);
            inputdata = Console.ReadLine();
            double time1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputdata);
            inputdata = Console.ReadLine();
            char name2 = Convert.ToChar(inputdata);
            inputdata = Console.ReadLine();
            double time2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputdata);
            inputdata = Console.ReadLine();

            if (time1 < time2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }

            else
     { Console.WriteLine(name2);

Comment: I've provided an answer below, you can check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this should do the trick.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iuaxMe) is the link so you can try it out.

```
    Console.WriteLine ("Name 1: ");
    string name1 = Console.ReadLine(); //put name into a string, so we can use it after

    Console.WriteLine ("Time 1: ");
    int time1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //put time into an int, so we can see who has better time

    Console.WriteLine ("Name 2: ");
    string name2 = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine ("Time 2: ");
    int time2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    
    if(time1 > time2) //checking who has better time
     Console.WriteLine(name1 + " has the better time."); //writing the name with the message
    else if(time1 < time2)
     Console.WriteLine(name2 + " has the better time.");
    else
      Console.WriteLine(name1 + " and " + name2 + " have the same time");
```

Answer (score 0):

To read full word you must use [Console.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-6.0) (Reads the next `line of characters` from the standard input stream). To better data representation you need to introduce some [class or struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/) that contains `Name` and `Time`. I add example according to your input data but if you want to add arbitrary number of elements than it's better to use [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) instead of `array` and [do-while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements) loop instead of `for loop`

```
public class Sprinter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }         
    public int Time { get; set; }
}
...
//Define array
var results = new Sprinter[2];
// Load data
for (var index = 0; index < results.Length; index++)
{
    results[index] = new Sprinter();
    results[index].Name = Console.ReadLine();
    results[index].Time = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? "0");
}
//Find minimum
var minTime = int.MaxValue;
Sprinter minElement = null;
for (var index = 0; index < results.Length; index++)
{
    var sprinter = results[index];
    if (sprinter.Time < minTime)
    {
        minElement = sprinter;
        minTime = sprinter.Time;
    }
}
//Show minimum
Console.WriteLine($"Min is {minElement.Name} with time {minElement.Time}");
```

---

Output:

```
Foo
200
Bar
300
Min is Foo with time 200
```